# Intersection of two parabolas where one is vertex shifted

Tags: conic-sections, quadratics

I would like to be able to calculate the intersections of two parabola's which accounts for one or both of the parabola's being shifted along the x axis

I have written an excel vba function to do this and it all works fine as long as the parabola's are in the form of $ax^2+bx+c$

If I try to use $a(x-h)^2+bx+c$ I cant seem to nut out the logic

I have included one of the VBA functions so you can see my working out, this function returns the intersecting x value(s)

```
Function QQInterceptX(a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2, pos)
' returns the x intercept
' y1=a1x^2+b1x+c1
' y2=a2x^2+b2x+c2
' when they intersect then the following is true
' a2x^2+b2x+c2=a1x^2+b1x+c1 as the y values are equivalent
' using algebra we get the following
' x=(a1x^2 - a2x^2) + (b1x - b2x) + (c1 - c2)
' x=(a1-a2)x^2 + (b1-b2)x + (c1-c2)
' we can then solve using the quadtratic formula
' x = (-(b1-b2) +/- sqrt((b1-b2)^2 - 4*(a1-a2)*(c1-c2)))/(2*(a1-a2))
' check for div by 0
If ((a1 - a2) <> 0) Then
' return the positive x intercept
  If (pos) Then
    QQInterceptX = (-(b1 - b2) + Sqr((b1 - b2) ^ 2 - 4 * (a1 - a2) * (c1 - c2))) / (2 * (a1 - a2))
  Else
    QQInterceptX = (-(b1 - b2) - Sqr((b1 - b2) ^ 2 - 4 * (a1 - a2) * (c1 - c2))) / (2 * (a1 - a2))
  End If
Else
  QQInterceptX = CVErr(xlErrNA)
End If
```

examples of the equations I am trying to solve are

$$x^2+138x+317=0$$
$$(x -33.33167)^2+2222=0$$

My online searches have produced no examples of what I am trying to do.

Its the step to the quadratic formula that loses me. and perhaps I should not be using the quadratic formula?

**Attribution**
To get me to the point of creating the VBA function I used this resource
http://zonalandeducation.com/mmts/intersections/intersectionOfTwoParabollas1/intersectionOfTwoParabolas1.htm

Disclosure: I have asked this question on physicsforums but am afraid I haven't understood the replies

Comment: Is there a problem with expanding $a (x-h)^2 + bx + c$ to $a x^2 + (b -2ha) x + (c + a h^2)$ and then using the method you already have with $b$ replaced by $b-2ha$ and $c$ replaced by $c + ah^2$?

Comment: I have given an answer for $x$-axis shifted standard parabolas. If you move to more general parabolas $a x^2 + b x + c$ these will include $x$-axis shifts, so one can drop that and straightly go for the intersection of two general parabolas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to be able to calculate the intersections of two
>   parabola's which accounts for one or both of the parabola's being
>   shifted along the x axis

Assuming a parabola means $y = x^2$.

The first parabola is shifted by $x_1$, the second by $x_2$:
$$
y_1(x) = (x - x_1)^2 \\
y_2(x) = (x - x_2)^2
$$

If they are both shifted the same amount, thus $x_1 = x_2$, the intersection set $S$ is
$$
S = \{ (x, y) \mid y = x^2 \} = G_{y_1} = G_{y_2}
$$
The intersection contains the whole parabola graphs of $y_1$, $y_2$.

If they are both shifted by different amounts, without loss of generality $x_1 < x_2$, we have for the intersection
$$
(x-x_1)^2 = (x-x_2)^2 \iff \\
x-x_1 = x - x_2 \vee  x - x_1 = x_2 - x \iff \\
x_1 = x_2 \vee x = \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2} \Rightarrow \\
x = \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2}
$$
Thus the intersection $S$ is
$$
S = \left\{ \left(
\frac{x_1 + x_2}{2}, \left(\frac{x_2-x_1}{2}\right)^2
\right) \right\}
$$
[image: intersecting shifted parabolas]

For the problem of the intersection of two general parabolas we have
$$
a_1 x^2 + b_1 x + c_1 = a_2 x^2 + b_2 x + c_2 \iff \\
(a_2 - a_1) x^2 + (b_2-b_1) x + (c_2 - c_1) = 0
$$
Depending on the parameters we can expect either infinite, 2, 1 or no point in the intersection set $S$.

Comment: The problem is for the two general parabola's. I am having trouble working out how to account for the (x-h)^2 part of the equation.

Comment: @DeveloperChris First, each shifted general one should be $a(x-h)^2 + b (x-h) + c = 0$, as each $x$ should be substituted with $x -h$, when $h$ is the shift amount.

Comment: @DeveloperChris Second: Just multiply out this equation: \begin{align}0 &= a(x-h)^2 + b(x-h) + c \\ &= ax^2 + ah^2 -2axh + bx - bh + c \\ &= a x^2 + (b - 2ah) x + (c-bh + ah^2) \\ &= a' x^2 + b' x + c'\end{align} with $a' = a$, $b' = b-2ah$ and $c' = c-bh+ah^2$, so it is still of the general form $ax^2 + bx+c = 0$, just with different parameters.

Comment: @DeveloperChris You had a version working for the general version? So just transfrom and put the new parameters in your solver.

Comment: Arrrghhhh of course $a(x-h)^2 + b (x-h) + c = 0$ why didn't I see that! Oh I know because I am stoopid. Many thanks.

Comment: That happens to the best of us! Just keep trying and have fun!

Comment: Sorry It took so long to get back to this. I only just rewrote the functions using your solution. Thanks for the great help

Comment: No problem. I am glad you made progress.